# Matching routes with hyphens in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have URLs like this;

```
http://0.0.0.0/country/bosnia-and-herzegovina-644
```

This is my Route declaration

```
<Route path="/country/:countrySlug-:countryId" component={CountryPage} />
```

So this doesnt work as the hyphen breaks it, how can I change it so I only extract the last hyphen as the param, I don't really want to change my slug generation system to use a different character as these are the most readable IMHO, but are only used for information, not content loading.

Thanks

Comment: as Tomasz mentions below, you can nest your routes and check on the matched URL

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do that, but maybe you could do this:

```
<Route path="/country/:country" component={CountryPage} />
```

then in the component:

```
const countryId = this.props.match.params.country.slice('-').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hyphen `-` sign for both parameters separation and words separation.

You can use hyphen `-` for parameters separation and underscore `_` for space between `countrySlug` words.

Here your URL will look like

http://0.0.0.0/country/bosnia_and_herzegovina-644

Now use this Route declaration

```
<Route path="/country/:countrySlug-:countryId" component={CountryPage} />
```

When you will generate your link don't forget to replace space with `_` sign otherwise your URL will look like this.

http://0.0.0.0/country/bosnia%20and%20herzegovina-644

But still, it will work fine.