# Condition valid and verified multiples times except once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react router with 5 pages, and check in 4 of them if I have a user logged in so that whether he is redirected, or displays the component.

It works perfectly for the 3 first pages, but the for the last "/create-channel", it won't work for some reason.

The value of loggedIn is true, and for the first 3 pages, it will valid the condition, but for the last, it seems it always redirect me to the login page.

I also tried doing this (reverse the condition):

```js
{loggedIn ? <CreateChannel/> : <Redirect to="/login"/>}
```

to

```js
{loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/login"/>: <CreateChannel/>}
```

but I still was redirected to login page. I have no idea of what is happening. The create-channel page doesn't have any redirection inside.

App.js

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core'
// Local
import Footer from './Footer'
import Header from './Header'
import Main from './Main'
import Login from './Login'
import Register from './Register'
import CreateChannel from './CreateChannel'
import { ChannelsContext } from './Contexts/ChannelsContext'
import { UserContext } from './Contexts/UserContext';
import { LoggedInContext } from './Contexts/LoggedInContext';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { getCookie } from './utils/cookies';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";


export default () => {
  //VARIABLES & HOOKS
  const styles = useStyles();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("My Account")
  const [channels, setChannels] = useState([{id: 0, name: 'channel 0'}]);
  const [drawerMobileVisible, setDrawerMobileVisible] = useState(false)
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false)
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect( () => {
    const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
      if(typeof getCookie('authorization') === "undefined"){
        setLoggedIn(false);
        console.log("Not logged in")
      }else{
        setLoggedIn(true);
        console.log("Logged in. Redirecting...")
      }
    }
    checkLoggedIn()
  }, [loggedIn])

  const darkModeToggleListener = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode)
    console.log(contextLoggedIn.loggedIn)
  }
  const drawerToggleListener = () => {
    setDrawerMobileVisible(!drawerMobileVisible)
  }

  const contextLoggedIn = {
    loggedIn: loggedIn,
    setLoggedInContext: setLoggedIn
  }

  const contextChannels = {
    channels: channels,
    setChannelsContext: setChannels
  }
  const contextUser = {
    username: username,
    setUserContext: setUsername
  }


  //RENDER
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <UserContext.Provider value={contextUser}>
    <LoggedInContext.Provider value={contextLoggedIn}>
    <ChannelsContext.Provider value={contextChannels}>
    <CssBaseline />
      <Router>
        <div className={styles.root}>
          <Header 
            drawerToggleListener={drawerToggleListener}
            darkModeToggleListener = {darkModeToggleListener}
          />

          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login">
              {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/welcome"/> : <Login onUser={setUsername}/>}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/register">
              {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/welcome"/> : <Register/>}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/welcome">
              {loggedIn ? <Main drawerMobileVisible={drawerMobileVisible} /> : <Redirect to="/login"/>}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/create-channel">
              {loggedIn ? <CreateChannel/> : <Redirect to="/login"/>}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/"> 
              <Redirect to="/login" />
            </Route>
          </Switch>

          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </ChannelsContext.Provider>
    </LoggedInContext.Provider>
    </UserContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

EDIT:
CreateChannel.js

```js
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core'
// Layout
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import ForumIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Forum';
import { UserContext } from './Contexts/UserContext'
import axios from 'axios';

/** INSPIRED FROM MUI DOCS https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/ */

const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    flex: '1 1 auto',
    background: theme.palette.background,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    '& > div': {
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
      marginTop: '1%',
      marginBottom: '1%',
      width: '30%',
    },
  },
  password:{
    width:'100%'
  },
  center:{
    width: 'auto',
  },
  icon:{
    width: '100%',
    height: '150px'
  }
});

export default () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null)
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null)
  const [userNotFound, setUserNotFound] = useState(false)
  const contextUser = useContext(UserContext)

  const styles = useStyles(useTheme());

  const handleCreateChannel = async () => {
    //First check if all users exists
    let userUnknown = false;
    let array = users.split(';')

    for(const elem of array){
      await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/users/${elem}`,{}, {withCredentials: true})
      .then(function (response){
        // eslint-disable-next-line
      }).catch(function (error){
        if(error.response.status === 404){
          userUnknown = true
        }
      })
    }

    //Then add yourself
    array.push(contextUser.username)

    //And finally add to db if all users are known
    if(!userUnknown){
      await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/channels',{
        name: name,
        users: array
      }, {withCredentials: true}).then(function (response){
        window.location.href = '/welcome';
      }).catch(function (error){
        if(error.response.status === 404){
        }
        else if(error.response.status === 401){
        }
      })
    }
    else{
      setUserNotFound(true)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div css={styles.root} >
      <Grid style={styles.center}>
        <ForumIcon
          color='primary'
          css={styles.icon}
        />
      </Grid>

      <Grid style={styles.center}>
        <Typography variant='h2' color='primary'>
          Create a channel
        </Typography>
      </Grid>

      <Grid>
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          id="name"
          label="Channel name"
          name="name"
          autoFocus
          fullWidth
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Grid>

      <Grid>
        <TextField
          error = {userNotFound}
          variant="outlined"
          id="users"
          label="Users (separated by a coma ) | BETA"
          name="Users"
          fullWidth
          helperText = {userNotFound ? "At least one user does not exist." : "Do not include yourself (automatically added)."}
          onChange={(e) => setUsers(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Grid>
        
      <Grid>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          margin = 'normal'
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          fullWidth
          onClick = {handleCreateChannel}
        >
          Create
        </Button>
      </Grid>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey SoaAlex and welcome to the community,

I think it is because of the hyphen in your path. I wasn't sure that it is possible so I did a search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56205249/7196883). Could you please verify this and try without a hyphen? You could try:

```
<Route path="/createChannel">
```

or

```
<Route path="/create_channel">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both of your solutions but unfortunatly, none of them works. This is really wierd. I can see for a milli second the URL going to /createChannel (or /create-channel) but I immediately get redirected to /login. Even more wierd, if I type `<Route path="/create-channel"> <CreateChannel/> </Route>`, it will work and redirect me to /create-channel page (but without loggin verification).

Comment: Could you provide the code of your createChannel component?

Comment: Sure. I edited my initial question with the full code

Comment: You have 2  console logs in your useEffect what is their output? You can set your console to not clear with page reloads.

Comment: If I am logged In, it will output twice « Logged In », and twice « Not logged In » otherwise, as expected.